# Relation between PATH env and argv[0]

Tags: c, linux

Generally argv[0] is as same as exec file name.  For example:

- If I execute program with `./my_program` then `argv[0]` is `./my_program`
- If I execute program with `/home/username/my_program` then `argv[0]` is `/home/username/my_program`.

My question is, if `PATH=/home/username` why I can't see `argv[0]` value?

This is my real situation

```
PATH=/home/knight/bin:/home/knight/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/knight
```

My test program source is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        printf("%s\n", argv[0]);
}
```

My home directory is `/home/knight` so I can execute program directly.

```
knight@knight-desktop:~$ test

knight@knight-desktop:~$ ./test
./test
```

I can't understand, why doesn't the `knight@knight-desktop:~$ test` command print any result?

Comment: `test` is a [bash keyword](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest), so you're not actually running your executable when you just type `test` at the command prompt.

Comment: Does @PaulR's observation make your entire question irrelevant, or do you still want to know the behavior for *other* program names?

Comment: On UNIX-like systems,environment variables are passed in via a pointer traditionally called env or argen. main has the signature int main(int argc, char **argv, char **argenv). Not portable to non-UNIX  of course

Comment: Using char * argenv[], then puts(argenv[0]); works in cmd window on windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `test` is a shell builtin command.

And there is a big difference between `./test`(it is an executable file) while `test` is a command passed direct to the shell of which if typed incorrect, it could have been not recognised for example lets say you use the command `tst` the result will be `-bash: tst: command not found`

To check if any word is a builtin command/reserved keyword for shell,use command `type`.

on terminal,

```
$type test
test is a shell builtin
$type if
if is a shell keyword
```